# How can I just extract one underbar-separated field from a filename?

Tags: bash, filenames, parameter-expansion

I have a list of file names like this:

`REG_2016120200hourly_d01_20161202_00_00_00.nc`

Of this name I would like to extract and put in a variable:

1)date 20161202

```
    for file in /path/*;
    do
     filename=$(basename -- "$file")
     date=${filename:4:8}
     echo $date
    done
```

and this is working, the script give me `20161202` and I don't know why

2)timestep 00

I need to take the firsts two zero 00 and I'm trying with

`timestep=${filename:34:36}` but this doesn't work.

I'm a little bit surprised because I used the same method in other scripts and I have never had problems.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timestep="${filename:34:2}"
```

`2` is length.

---

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter:offset:length}`: Substring Expansion. Expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset. [...]